# R - Replacing part of a string with a for loop and gsub

Tags: r, string, loops, replace, gsub

I have two data frames (df1 and df2) and I want to replace part of the strings in df1 with the corresponding string in df2.

For example: The result should be df3

```
a <- c("extra text test-ID 1", "extra text test-ID 2", "extra text test-ID 3", "extra text test-ID 4")
b <- c("experiment 5","experiment 6","experiment 7","experiment 8") 
c <- c("exercise 9","exercise 10","exercise 11","exercise 12")

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
names(df1) <- c('a','b','c')

d <- c("test-ID 1", "test-ID 2", "test-ID 4")
e <- c("test-ID 1098", "test-ID 245", "test-ID 77")

df2 <- data.frame(d,e)
names(df2) <- c('a','b')

df1
df2

f <- c("extra text test-ID 1098", "extra text test-ID 245", "extra text test-ID 3", "extra text test-ID 77")
g <- c("experiment 5","experiment 6","experiment 7","experiment 8") 
h <- c("exercise 9","exercise 10","exercise 11","exercise 12")

df3 <- data.frame(f,g,h)
names(df3) <- c('a','b','c')
df3
```

I want to execute this with a function.

```
replacefunction <- function(x) {
  cat(paste("searching for ", x, "\n"))
  for (i in seq_along(df2$a)) {
    old <- df2$a[i]
    new <- df2$b[i]
    if (grepl(old, x)) { 
      cat(paste0('found ', '"', old, '"', "\n"))
      return(gsub(old, new, x))
    }
  }
}
```

However, this gives a warning:

```
df4 <- replace_values(df1$a)

Warning message:
In if (grepl(old, x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Only the first entry in column df1$a is changed, why  does this happen?

Comment: I'm not entirely following the logic of how you want to get from one data frame to the next. But that warning comes up when you use an `if ... else` statement on a vector with more than one element. This misses one of the beauties of R, which is [vectorized operations](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-vectorize-your-functions-in-r/). Functions like `grepl` will work over an entire vector--no need for a loop to go through it one element at a time

Comment: @camille `grepl` won't help much here, by itself, because there are multiple replacements as well as multiple patterns to match.

Comment: That's true. Like I said, I'm not getting all the logic going from one string to the next. But `grepl` is what's throwing this warning, so it seems this is an instance of using `if ... else` that won't work instead of a vectorized function like `ifelse`. Unless the purpose is to find if the string is in *any* element, in which case `ifelse(any(grepl(...))` might be it?

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. Yes the purpose is to find the string in any element, however `ifelse(any(grepl(...))` creates the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R approach, mainly relying on the `apply` functions.  I *almost* like my answer, except that I had to resort to using an explicit `for` loop inside the innermost call to `sapply`.  This loop iterates over all rows of your `df2` pattern/replacement data frame, and attempts to make replacements on each element of the input data frame `df1`.

```
d <- c("test-ID 1", "test-ID 2", "test-ID 4")
d <- paste0("\\b", d, "\\b")
e <- c("test-ID 1098", "test-ID 245", "test-ID 77")

df2 <- data.frame(d,e)
names(df2) <- c('a','b')

df1
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {    # apply function(x) to each element of df1
    sapply(x, function(y) {
        for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
            y <- gsub(df2[i, "a"], df2[i, "b"], y)
        }
        return(y)
    })
})

df1

                     a            b           c
1 extra text test-ID 1 experiment 5  exercise 9
2 extra text test-ID 2 experiment 6 exercise 10
3 extra text test-ID 3 experiment 7 exercise 11
4 extra text test-ID 4 experiment 8 exercise 12
                        a            b           c
1 extra text test-ID 1098 experiment 5  exercise 9
2  extra text test-ID 245 experiment 6 exercise 10
3    extra text test-ID 3 experiment 7 exercise 11
4   extra text test-ID 77 experiment 8 exercise 12
```

I use `sub` to handle the replacement logic, and since this works with regex patterns, I surrounded your target patterns with words boundaries.  That is, I match `\btest-ID 1\b` rather than just `test-ID 1`, the latter which would also match this term should it occur as a substring in some other text.

Comment: So far it seems this is the solution. I'm sampling my original data set to validate. Thank you.

Comment: H Rene, there is an R user on the site called @akrun who could probably give a better answer.  This was the best I could do :-)